# Switching review queue when approve edit

Tags: support, bug, review-queues

1. Open First posts review queue.
2. Click <kbd>edit (1)</kbd> link under the post with suggested edit (still in First posts queue).
3. Approve this edit.
4. From now you are reviwing Suggested edits queue instead of first posts.

Is such behaviour correct? I expected to be in First posts queue after approving an edit.